# Ipad/Iphone double click/tap issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad

somebody, let me know some idea about double click/tap issue in Ipad/Iphone.

I have a web application which render on iPhone. but on the page there are such element where hover perform. it effects when  i am going to click on the element it has to be click twice.

I got a [link](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/) but I have the same application which render on desktop also.

Would you please suggest me good solution?